# RxJava groupby time bound

Tags: rx-java, reactive-programming

I am pretty new to RXJava and reactive programming.

I have a stream of requests which I need to group by IP addresses

`[Start-timestamp] [reqId] [ip-address]`

```
Observable<GroupedObservable<String, Trace>> groupedEntriesObservable =
            windowedLogEntries.groupBy(trace-> trace.getIP());
```

but how can I get only the ones which are 5ms apart from their first one's starttimestamp?
Eg.

so, if I have

`{0ms,id1,ip1}, {1ms,id2,ip1}....{3ms,id3,ip1}, {7ms,id4,ip1}....{15ms,id5,ip1}`

then the filtered group is:

`{id1,id2,id3}`

The rest are rejected since their timestamp is more than 0ms+5ms